# Flaskを使ったルーティングがうまくいかずエラーが出る

Tags: python, python3, flask, sqlalchemy, url-routing

**実現したいこと**
フォームに入力した文字列がデータベースに格納され、HTMLのページに反映されるプログラムをPython・FlaskとSQLAlchemyを使って書いています。

**困っていること**

```
$ FLASK_APP=app.py FLASK_DEBUG=true flask run
```

として実行すると以下のエラーが表示され、画面が読み込まれません。
解決方法が分からず困っています。

エラー文（書いたプログラム以外のファイルに関する、実行後レスポンスの記述は省略しています）

```
File "/Users/username/Desktop/app.py", line 18, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'
```

line18というと以下に当たるのですが、どのように修正すれば良いのでしょうか。

```
@app.route('/todos/create', method=['POST'])
```

**実行しているコード**
index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="/todos/create">
        <input type= "text" name="description" />
        <input type= "submit" value="Create" />
    </form>
    <ul>
        {% for d in data %}
        <li>{{d.description}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

app.py

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://username@localhost:5432/todoapp'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'todos'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Todo {self.id}{self.description}>'

db.create_all()

@app.route('/todos/create', method=['POST'])
def create_todo():
  description = request.form.get('description', '')
  todo = Todo(description=description)
  db.session.add(todo)
  db.session.commit()
  return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', data=Todo.query.all())
```

**実行環境**
Flask 1.1.1
sqlalchemy　1.3.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

気づきにくいミスだと思いますが、`method`ではなく`methods`です。

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#url-route-registrations

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
Rubyなどでも、変数が複数形か単数形でエラーになるというようなことがありました。Webアプリケーションにおいては単なる「変数名」ではなく、複数形か単数形でなぜちがいが生じるのでしょうか。
疑問を抱かずにそういうものとして、考えるべきでしょうか。

Comment: 単なる「変数名」だからですね。FLaskが定義した変数名が「複数形」であるだけです。どのプログラム言語でも一緒ですが一文字でも違うと変数としては違うものになります。methodsを使ってくれとFlaskが定義しているのに、methodやmathodsを使ったら、存在しない変数なのでエラーになりますね。